# Load default option of database into selected option

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function that load a simple select like:

```
function cargarCatalogo() {
            apiService.get("../../api/Catalogo/GetCatalogoPadre/" + $scope.Catalogo + "/",
                null,
                function(res) {
                    $scope.Catalogos = res.data;
                    $scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];
                   inicial
                    $scope.filtro($scope.selected);
                },
                errorCatalogo);
        }
```

As you can see I select first option as default with `$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];` Problem is I don´t want that option as selected I want to be selected value of database because I´m ussing Edit View.

My table is like this:

```
+--------+----------+---------+
|     ID |  Nombre  | PadreID |
+--------+----------+---------+
|      1 | KENWORTH |       0 |
|      2 | VOLVO    |       0 |
|      3 | T6000    |       2 |
|      4 | T800     |       1 |
+--------+----------+---------+
```

If I edit register T6000 I will receive `KENWORTH` and `VOLVO` in select,  but PadreID equals to 2, so I want a default option will be 2? what I need to change as selected value? Regards

**HTML:**

```
<select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
```

`$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];` result:

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code you are using for the `select` in your html?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded it into my question @DanielWarke

Comment: I know how to accomplish this using `ng-repeat` and `ng-selected`, but I'm not very familiar with `ng-options`. Would you be interested in seeing a solution using these methods instead?

Comment: Show me please @DanielWarke

Comment: Which property of Catalogos do you want to display in the view, and which one do you want to actually be assigned to `$scope.selected`?

Answer (score 0):

if you have the id of the needed select item, you can use `ng-options="item.Codigo as item.Nombre for item in Catalogos ">` the `ng-model` of the `select` will hold the `Codigo` and the view to the user will show `Nombre`

can you try this 
`<select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected.Codigo" ng-options="item.Codigo as item.Nombre for item in Catalogos"></select>`

Comment: @Ledwing did `$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];` hold the `Codigo` number ?

Comment: Yes, I show you in picture in my question, can you review it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149513/discussion-between-abd-elrahman-telb-and-ledwing).

Comment: Now, it always return first option, shoud I delete line `$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];` ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally find the syntax `ng-options` difficult to read and understand, I've always preferred using `ng-repeat` with `ng-bind`, `ng-value`, and `ng-selected` to achieve similar results. Here's how you can accomplish this using an alternative method:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected">
        <option ng-repeat="item in Catalogos" ng-bind="item.Nombre" ng-value="item.Codigo" ng-selected="item.ID === object.ID"></option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure how you're wanting to set which option is selected, but to use `ng-selected`, you need any property in the current `item` to evaluate to true when compared with another value.

ngSelected docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected

Comment: Should I remove this line of code ? `$scope.selected = $scope.Catalogos[0];`

Comment: I'm not sure. Which option are you wanting to be selected initially? Is there a condition that you want to match, such as default select the option that has a Nombre of 'Volvo'?

Comment: I want selected of my database for example if I clic edit into T6000 it have `PadreId = 2` so I selected should be VOLVO  who has `Id = 2` but if I edit T800 with `PadreID =1` selected should be `KENWORTH` who has `Id = 1`

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure if I have this right, but `ng-selected="item.Padre == selected.ID"` I would recommend using something different for your `ng-model` however.